# Summernote not functioning. Just display text line

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, summernote

I have a html page. Which summernote is supposed to function on as a mail compose form. I have followed the instructions for installation to the letter. Due to the code being rather large I have included it in a pastebin available here: http://pastebin.com/07xc8pJs

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around. If I move the form section to a different file and use iframe it functions fine.